# Grub2 not finding windows partition

Tags: grub2, grub, gentoo, grub2-mkconfig

I have brand new laptop with windows 10. Using NVME ssd drive.  I am trying to do multiboot using UEFI.

For some reason, `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` is not finding my windows partition. I have my UEFI partition mounted to `/boot`.

I have installed grub with `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot`. I can see `/boot/EFI/gentoo` along with the windows directory.

Any ideas how to make grub-mkconfig see my windows 10 partition?

Comment: I'm not familiar with UEFI, (I was able to get dual boot working with one of these [Windows (MSDOS based boot loaders)](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2/Chainloading#Windows_.28MSDOS_based_boot_loaders.29)), but UEFI appears to be included here [Dual-booting Windows on UEFI with GPT](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2/Chainloading#Dual-booting_Windows_on_UEFI_with_GPT), maybe it can help.

Answer (score 3):

You need `sys-boot/os-prober` to detect windows. From the Grub2 Gentoo [wiki page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2#Additional_software):

> ### Additional software
>
> Optionally, install the os-prober utility (provided through the
>   sys-boot/os-prober package) to have GRUB2 probe for other operating
>   systems when running the grub-mkconfig command. In most instances,
>   this will enable GRUB2 to automatically detect other operating systems
>   including Windows 7, 8.1, 10, other distributions of Linux, etc. root
>
> `emerge --ask --newuse sys-boot/os-prober`
>
> The GRUB2 (and optionally sys-boot/os-prober) installations do not
>   automatically enable the boot loader. These only install the software
>   on the operating system, but to install the boot loader to the system
>   itself (so that it is used when booting the system), additional steps
>   need to be taken, which are covered in the [Configuration](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2#Configuration) section.

And:

> ### [os-prober and UEFI in chroot](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2#os-prober_and_UEFI_in_chroot)
>
> The sys-boot/os-prober utility is used to discover alternate installs,
>   such as Microsoft Windows. To function properly, it needs to have
>   access to information from the live environment's udev to test for the
>   EFI System Partition.
>
> Run these commands in the host environment to provide the required
>   files (example shows Gentoo mounted on /mnt/gentoo like in the
>   Handbook):
>
> ```
> root #mkdir -p /mnt/gentoo/run/udev 
> root #mount -o bind /run/udev /mnt/gentoo/run/udev 
> root #mount --make-rslave /mnt/gentoo/run/udev`
> ```